# Can Arduino run WiFi if powered only with disposable batteries?

Tags: arduino

I'm brand new to the Arduino world.

I'm interested in building an Arduino app such that when a button it pressed, the Arduino connects to WiFi and through this Wifi connection accesses a publicly-accessible Web API over HTTP. Accessing the API takes less than 1 second. After this, the whole system should go to sleep until the next time the button is pressed.

The tricky thing is that I want to power this Arduino with disposable (ie: non-rechargable) batteries -- either a single 9V battery or two AA batteries. But I don't know if this is feasible. How much battery power will be consumed by connecting to a Wifi Network? How much battery power will be consumed simply to operate the Arduino chip? Is what I'm suggesting feasible? Do disposable batteries pack enough juice to power this application for hundreds of button-presses?

Comment: you can use the spec sheets of all the hardware and simple math to figure this out yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware issue, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can power an Arduino with disposable batteries.  If you want to minimize the power consumption, I'd recommend bypassing the onboard voltage regulator and powering the Arduino through its 5V pin using a switching or an LDO regulator like the [LM2936](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2936.pdf) - these are very efficient and will consume very little power when the board is asleep.

You didn't say which Arduino you're using, or what you're using for wi-fi connectivity, so I can't answer as to what the power requirements of your device would be.  But I don't see any reason it would be unfeasable to power it with AA batteries.

I'd recommend against using a 9V battery if long battery life is a consideration.  Use AA batteries instead, if you have room.  You'll need 4 of them (1.5V x 4 = 6V) because the Arduino needs at least 5 volts to run.  But 4 AAs will have a much higher current capacity than a 9V, so they will last much longer.